# How is $(2^a)^{\lg n} = n^a$?

Tags: logarithms, self-learning, polylogarithm

I was learning from *Introduction to Algorithms* (Chapter 3 under the topic “Logarithms”) and came across this expression.

$$
  \lim_{ n \to 0 }{\frac{\lg^b n}{(2^a)^{\lg n}}}
  =
  \lim_{n \to 0} \frac{\lg^bn}{n^a} = 0 ,
$$
where $\lg$ is $\log_2$.

I don't understand how $(2^a)^{\lg n}$ changed to $n^a$. Please can someone explain it to me.

Comment: $(2^a)^{\lg n} = 2^{a \lg n} = (2^{\lg n})^a = n^a$. It is that simple.

Comment: I think you were writing "log" instead of lg, weren’t you? I haven’t seen "lg" before. And use $\log$ for writing "log".

Comment: @BillyIstiak Personally, I often see "$\lg$" as an abbreviation for $\log_{10}$. But I guess this is just the notation of the author, so it's acceptable

Comment: @NikolaTolzsek thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because$$(2^a)^{\lg n}=2^{a\lg(n)}=\left(2^{\lg(n)}\right)^a=n^a.$$